# jquery template sending data

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I am using Jquery templates.
In that I am having the Json body and value of data in Variable defined in the same file I am sending to the client

Now I have a different process that gets the data from DataBase.
so, how do I send the data to the client

the Jquerytemplate + JSON Body.

how do I send that?

Comment: terminolgy hard to follow... what does **`having the Json body hard coded`** mean? You can pass a template string to most template systems so it also matters which specific template system you are using. This means you could include the template string in your json

Comment: you can send json data in hidden field

Comment: how do I send that in a hidden field